# Kendogrid Paging not working using scrollable: virtual is true

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-mobile

I am using kendogrid but got error with paging
i think if use virtual: true property in this case issue create

Please check below demo url with virtual: true property

https://js.do/code/292359

Recreated step for this issue :

1. select page no 3
2. now scrolling in grid
3. please check page refresh working but after scroll page automatic set to 1 page.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, using virtual scrolling with paging isn't supported according to [Telerik support](https://www.telerik.com/forums/scrolling-issues-when-both-virtual-scrolling-and-paging-are-enabled#GYW3TI7JBkmIPGlDzVAXzg):

> The idea of virtual scrolling is to be used without paging. Using both features at the same time is unfortunately not supported.